# Firebase Facebook authentication on localhost

Tags: javascript, firebase, facebook, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I have a Vue.js app that uses Firebase for authentication and I'm trying to wire up the Facebook provider. I believe I have all my Firebase related code and configuration correct, but when I test my implementation from `http://localhost:8080`), I keep getting the `Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains.` Facebook error.

[image]

The problem, from what I can tell, is that I need to provide a valid "callback" URL that returns the authentication response to my application. This is what Firebase tells you to do when setting up Facebook authentication, and what my research of the error confirmed, but the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field in the Facebook App Settings page (which is where I surmised I need to put my return URL) rejects URLs containing `localhost`. I even tried to add the URL to any of the other fields in the Settings pages that look like they want URLs but they all respond the same. Here's a screenshot demonstrating this:

[image]

So my questions are 1) how do I configure my Facebook App to allow localhost testing, and 2) how do I fix the `Can't load URL` Facebook error?

Let me know if I need to include my pre-login Vue code. FWIW, I use Firebase's `linkWithRedirect();` and `signInWithRedirect()` methods for logging in (as opposed to `linkWithPopup()` and `signInWithPopup()`).

Comment: Can you try it without the port?

Comment: @ceejayoz So removing the port doesn't seem to make a difference but if I remove the protocol, it accepts it as `https://localhost/__/auth/handler` (it's now `https` and not `http` anymore), and if I then try the login again the error changes to `URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.` It doesn't feel like we're moving in the right direction but I'll see what I can find on this new error.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you're supposed to paste the exact `.../__/auth/handler` URL that Firebase gives you into the Facebook Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field, even while still developing locally. I was under the impression that the URL should be adapted to the environment - i.e. `http://localhost:8080/__/auth/handler` for development and `https://my-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler` for production.

But nope, use the production URL even in development.